# How is OEIS sequence A120933 'maximal leading nondecreasing subword ' to be understood?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary

For n=2 we only have these four binary words:

00
01
10
11

What is the procedure for calculating by hand T(2,1) and T(2,2)?

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this sequence as I can't see the logic behind it at n=2 much less for n=>3.

Answer (score 1):

00 starts with 00 which is non-decreasing so k=2
01 starts with 01 which is non-decreasing so k=2
10 starts with 1, but 10 is not non-decreasing, so k=1
11 starts which 11, so k=2
Three of them have k=2, one has k=1,
so T(2,1)=1,T(2,2)=3

Comment: Thanks, I was making it more complicated than necessary! Curiously, if you toss a fair coin 1024 times, 256 tosses are expected to be in runs of 1, 256 tosses in runs of 2, then 192,128,80,48,28,16,9 tosses in runs of 3,4,5,6,7,8,9  (if 256 tosses are in runs of 2 then 256/2=128 runs of 2, 80 tosses in runs of 5 give 16 runs of 5 heads or 5 tails). The last entry, 11, are the tosses left over that don't fit into runs which have expected probability of one. I'm still working on understanding the connection between fair coin runs and maximal subruns. Would you happen to be able to shed some joy?

Comment: To clarify: what is the connection between a120933 T(n,k) and the number of tosses in runs of k when tossing a fair coin 2^n times? The only modification necessary is when k=n, so the last entry in every row is the number of tosses left over when the others have been allocated in runs from length 1 up to and including runs of length (n-1). Curious, no?

Comment: To be in a run of 1, either it is one end, and the chance is 50%, or it is one of the other 1022, and the chance is 1 in 4.  The total is 256.5 tosses out of 1024.

Comment: If you loop the 1024 tosses back to the start, then you get the same values as a120933.  There are $k$ different runs of length $k$ that include a given coin, which gives the $k$ factor.  Then powers of 2 go down the longer the run is.  Quite different reasons from a120933, but the same result.